# python + maya: Graph selected node's shaders to hypershade network

Tags: python, maya

I've written a script that gets the shaders being used by the selected objects. I then want to graph  those shaders to the network in the hypershade. What am I missing here?

I've managed to get it working on this small snippet but not on the main code...

small test snippet:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
blinn = cmds.createNode('blinn')
cmds.hyperShade(blinn)
```

Main code:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

# get selected nodes:
nodes = cmds.ls(selection=True, dag=True)
nodeCount = len(nodes)

# get shading groups from shapes:
if nodeCount >= 1:
    shadingGroups = cmds.listConnections(nodes, t='shadingEngine')
shadingGroupsCount = len(shadingGroups)

# get the shaders:
if shadingGroupsCount >= 1:
    shaders = cmds.ls(cmds.listConnections(shadingGroups), materials=1) 

# graph shaders to the network in the hypershade:
if shaders >= 1:
    cmds.hyperShade(shaders)

print shaders
```

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as from what I can determine from your code, you're after the MATERIALS of the select object(s).

So this will loop over the objects and add their shader to the graph. Initially, it will clear the graph before it starts adding, you can remove that functionality by simply clearing the flags `resetGraph=True, dependGraphArea=True`.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as mel

nodes = cmds.ls(selection=True, dag=True)
## Open the panel, doesn't re-open if already up and sets focus
cmds.HypershadeWindow()
## Get the name of the hsPanel
hsPanel = cmds.getPanel(withFocus=True)
## Clear the graph
cmds.hyperShade(resetGraph=True, dependGraphArea=True)
for node in nodes:
    if len(nodes) > 0:
        ## Select a node
        cmds.select(node, r=1)
        ## List the materials assigned to the object
        cmds.hyperShade(shaderNetworksSelectMaterialNodes=1)
        ## Create an array of the materials
        materialSelection = cmds.ls(sl=1)
        ## Loop over the materials and graph them        
        for material in materialSelection:
            # cmds.select(material, r=1)
            try:
                cmds.hyperGraph(hsPanel, edit=True, addDependNode=material)
            except:
                mel.eval("hyperShadePanelGraphCommand(\"%s\", \"addSelected\")" % hsPanel)

    else:
        cmds.warning("Please select an object")
```

<del>I'm not happy with using the mel eval statement `hyperShadePanelGraphCommand()`, however I couldn't find a substitute with python. Happy for someone to correct that!</del>

Comment: I edited your script for you. It wasn't working for me though (and still isn't), because `hsPanel` is giving me a `modelPanel` instead.

Comment: Ironically @mhlester I get an error trying to run your script too, `# Error: RuntimeError: file <maya console> line 23: hyperGraph: Object 'modelPanel4' not found. # ` might be a versioning problem, 2014?

Comment: I'm on 2012 (Don't laugh. We'll upgrade off Windows XP once our current project wraps up)

Comment: Were you *not* getting the error in your original version?

Comment: Nope it worked for me just fine and still does, very odd... Maybe my new solution is better?

Comment: That way if one fails, we have a fallback

Comment: The first won't fail. Might as well just roll back to rev 1

Comment: I reversed the try/except, seeing as it failed for me, and your way is generally nicer, we'll try yours firts.